# Solr Configuration

Tags: java, solr

I tried to installed Solr using:

```
java -jar start.jar
```

However I downloaded the source code and didn't compile it (Didn't pay attention). And the error was:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/

HTTP ERROR: 404
Problem accessing /solr/admin/. Reason:
NOT_FOUND
```

Then I downloaded the compiled version of solr but when trying to run the example configuration I'm getting exception:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Is there a way to revert solr configuration and start from scratch? Looks like the configuration got messed up. I don't see anything related to it in the manual.

Here is the error:

```
2011-07-10 22:41:27.631:WARN::failed SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8983: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
2011-07-10 22:41:27.632:WARN::failed Server@c4e21db: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
2011-07-10 22:41:27.632:WARN::EXCEPTION 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketConnector.java:80)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:283)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
Jul 10, 2011 10:41:27 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore registerSearcher
INFO: [] Registered new searcher Searcher@5b6b9e62 main
```

Answer (score 17):

This means you already have an application running on that particular port.

Run:

```
$ lsof -i :8983
```

This gives you a list of any application running on that port. In my case, Solr is already running, and I get back:

```
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    10289 patricia  111u  IPv6 399410      0t0  TCP *:8983 (LISTEN)
```

Kill this process by filling in your PID:

```
$ kill 10289
```

And then try running Solr again.

Answer (score 9):

The `java.net.BindException` means that you are attempting to restart `solr` while an earlier instance continues to run, or less probably that you have something else running on port 8983. You should find that process, kill it, and then start `solr` again.

Answer (score 6):

Its bound to a some other application. In case if its a important app you can change jetty default port using following:

```
java -Djetty.port=8181 -jar start.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ps aux  | grep solr
```

OR

```
ps aux | grep start.jar
```

AND the get then process id and kill it:

```
kill -9 #PID#
```

example : kill -9 4989

UPDATE:
after killing the process if you want to reinstall solr you soul first uninstall it, the following is one of the solutions to uninstall it:

```
sudo service solr stop
sudo rm -r /var/solr
sudo rm -r /opt/solr-5.3.1
sudo rm -r /opt/solr
sudo rm /etc/init.d/solr
sudo deluser --remove-home solr
sudo deluser --group solr
```

An now you can reinstall it with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If `sudo lsof -i:8983` won't help finding application running on the same port, the common mistake is Tomcat misconfiguration (if you're using it).

For example by default Tomcat listens on port 8005 for SHUTDOWN command and if you set another Connector to listen on the same port, you'll get port conflict.

So please double check in `server.xml` if these ports are different:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Connector port="8983" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some crazy idea is to use docker to read a complete extended step by step and repeatable installation:

Here dockerhub to select the specific version tu run in docker [Docker Hub Solr](https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/)

And here github to read the docker recipe [Solr docker Recipe](https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr/blob/dfe2c80ca10ca9191ae8ce7c6193ecd47c6c0b5f/5.3/Dockerfile)